# How to delete padding in DataGrid?

Tags: c#

I don't understand why I have this space (padding) between DataGrid frame and it content. I marked this space in red at the screenshot

[image]

There is a picture without red mark for better viewing

[image]

It looks a little bit strange... just a space without any reason.

There is my `.xalm`

```
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >

                <GroupBox Header="Main configuration :" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Height="Auto">

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GridItems}"
                                  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Gray"
                                  CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                                  CanUserResizeRows="False"
                                  CanUserSortColumns="False"
                                  VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
                                  x:Name="Dg_main_configuration"
                                  CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                                  PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Dg_main_configuration_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
                                      AlternatingRowBackground="LightYellow"
                                      CanUserAddRows="False"
                                      MinHeight="150"
                                      MaxHeight="150"
                                      Grid.Column="0"
                                      AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn 
                                    IsReadOnly="True"
                                    Header="Path to calibration folder" 
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=ClipFolder}"/>

....
....
```

As you can see there is any line about padding or margin....

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If i recall, setting `RowHeaderWidth = 0` should solve it

Comment: @AleksaRistic yes, thanks! You can publish your answer I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gray thing you see is indeed `RowHeader`, setting it's property to 0 will result in hiding it.

`RowHeaderWidth = 0` does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This is not padding nor margin to me. You just have row headers visible but with no value. To get rid of it, just set `RowHeadersVisible` property of your DataGrid to `False`.

Source : [API doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid.rowheadersvisible?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: There is no `RowHeadersVisible` property in `DataGrid`

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Well, it depends on what DataGrid you're using. Its exists in _System.Windows.Forms_ namespace. But indeed i did'nt know there was no property like this in _System.Windows.Controls_... My bad. Though it might be useful for others i will not delete my answer. :)